# Comparing numerical strings and formatting integers with leading zeros in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, numbers, string-formatting

how i use the number 05798300 exact in ruby?
When i enter: 
2.0.0p247 :031 > 05798300
SyntaxError: (irb):31: Invalid octal digit

or

2.0.0p247 :001 > 04704110
 => 1280072

I need check if the number: 04704110 is between 0100000000 and 09000000.

Comment: why do you have the 0 in the front?

Comment: Because in Brazil, streets have zipcode init with 0 for region of the São Paulo City... I need verify if zipcode informed by user is in São Paulo City :/

Comment: You have to treat the numbers in postal codes as strings, not integers.

Comment: a leading `0` means the number is [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). Remove the leading zeros.

Comment: Certainly you could combine the approaches and slice off the leading zero, coerce the string to an integer, do your comparison, and then use the original string for storing it (I'm assuming you wanted to do that).  Or you could just check if it leads with zero if that's all you need and not do a numeric comparison.

Comment: `0100000000` has 10 digits. Is that a typo? Brazilian postal codes seem to have either five or eight digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep leading zeros, store your postal codes as strings and you can compare them as such:

```
test  = '04704110'
lower = '01000000' #assuming eight digits
upper = '09000000'

p lower < test && test < upper
#=> true
```

Otherwise, compare them as integers but format them when you print them, adding leading zeros:

```
test = 4704110
p "%08d" % test
#=> "04704110"
```